# Moving of Outlook.MAPI folder to another folder

Tags: c#

I am working on a VSTO project using C#. I am facing an issue and I need your help regarding that. I want not to allow users to be able to move an Outlook.MAPI folder into another folder (such as: Inbox, SentItems, etc ...). Is that possible ? Is there a specific property where I can set for this folder so that the users can't move it to another folder. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

**No. Not really.**

You could provide your own store, and then you can do whatever you want.
You may also be interested in [Outlook Folder Permissions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/outlook-folder-permissions-HP005242287.aspx) (it comes with severe restrictions, such as requiring an Exchange mailbox and issues such as implicit ownership of a personal mailbox -- [Details of the Exchange Access Control Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123461%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx)).

Removing control of THEIR FOLDERS is likely going to break things or make them hate you.

My recommendations:

- Hide the folder; move it outside of the IPM tree or use the PR_ATTR_HIDDEN property
- Recover the folder if it is moved/deleted
- Continue to work even if the folder has a new location
- Seek alternatives solutions/approaches to problem